# Как посчитать в JavaScript, сколько расстояния наскроллил пользователь?

Tags: javascript

Хочу посчитать сколько туда сюда в пикселях пользователь всего наскроллил чтобы понимать его действия. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Хочу посчитать сколько туда сюда в пикселях пользователь всего наскроллил чтобы понимать его действия. Как это можно сделать?

Вот такой вариант, подсчёта.

```js
var distance = 0;
window.onscroll = function(e) {
  distance +=window.scrollY;
  console.log(distance); // В пикселях
};
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">&nbsp;</div>
```

- window.onscroll - события скрола.
- window.scrollY - число пикселей пролистанных по вертикали.

---

**UPD:**

```js
var distance = 0;
var total = 0;
window.onscroll = function(e) {
  distance += window.scrollY - distance;
  total += distance;
  console.info(distance, total); // В пикселях
};
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Немного не правильно решили. Для решения задачи необходимо высчитывать кол-во пикселей, которое пробежал бегунок - и суммировать это значение. А у Вас суммируется глубина прокрутки.

Answer (score 0):

Подброшу свои 5 копеек, вдруг кому пригодится:

```js
let divScrollEnabled = document.querySelector('.test'),
  wheel = "wheel" || "mousewheel" || "MozMousePixelScroll",
  count = 0,
  scrollTo = e => {
    let delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;
    count += (delta > 0) ? Math.abs(delta) : Math.abs(delta);
    console.log(count);
  };
(divScrollEnabled.addEventListener) ?
divScrollEnabled.addEventListener(wheel, scrollTo):
  divScrollEnabled.attachEvent(wheel, scrollTo);
window.onunload = () => divScrollEnabled.removeEventListener('mousewheel', scrollTo) ||
  divScrollEnabled.detachEvent(wheel, scrollTo);
```

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #42A5F5;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Крути, Форест! КРУТИ!</div>
```

Comment: У вашего способа есть 1 недостаток: считается только скролл колесиком мыши, но если потянуть за бегунок - скрол не суммируется

Comment: Есть и другой недостаток: если бегунок упрется в пол/потолок, но пользователь будет продолжать крутить колесико, то счетчик будет работать